# How to check if droppable area is reached with the draggable element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

When i'm dragging the draggable element, and its over the droppable area, i want to add a new class to the draggable element so i can change its style using CSS. This is what i got so far:

```
<aside>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</aside>
<section></section>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 //Test 
    $("aside div").draggable({
  revert: "invalid",
  containment: "document",
  helper: "clone",
  cursor: "move"
 });
 
    $('section').droppable({
  accept: "aside div",
  activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
   //valami
   alert('lol');
  }
    });
 
});
```

```css
aside {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
}

aside div {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
}

section {
    float:right;
    width:400px;
    height:320px;
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<aside>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</aside>
<section></section>
```

Comment: Use over event!
http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From jQueryUi Documentation http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-over

> `over( event, ui )Type: dropover`
>
> Triggered when an accepted draggable is dragged over the droppable
>   (based on thetolerance option).

You might be interested in its dual also

> `out( event, ui )Type: dropout`
>
> Triggered when an accepted draggable is dragged out of the droppable
>   (based on thetolerance option).

Comment: I was looking for a similar event for draggable, but i'm guessing i can add a class to the draggable div from here too. Thanks.

Comment: in the over function, `ui.draggable` is the draggable that just went over the droppable. Unfortunately the out function does not have it so you will have to find a different solution for your cleanup.